# Symfony2 - Authentication when creating a simple login form

Tags: php, symfony, oop, authentication

I'm following this tutorial to create a simple login form:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/security/form_login_setup.html

This is my `security.yml` file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 12

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        password: pass
                        roles: ROLE_ADMIN
                    foo:
                        password: foo
                        roles: ROLE_USER

    firewalls:
         dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            form_login: 
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager

     access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

This is the controller:

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request) {

        return $this->render('AtBundle:Default:login.html.php');
    }

    /**
    * @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
    */
    public function loginCheckAction() {

        $this->addFlash('warning', $this->get('translator')->trans('login_expired'));
        return $this->render('AtBundle:Default:login_check.html.php');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
    */
    public function logoutAction() {

        $this->addFlash('warning', $this->get('translator')->trans('login_expired'));
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('login'));
    }



}
```

And this is the form:

```
//login.html.php
<form action= /login_check method="post">

<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" />

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" />

<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token"
    value="<?php echo $view['form']->csrfToken('authenticate') ?>">
<button type="submit">login</button>
```

The fact is that when I'm trying to authenticate, every username and password I enter, are considered legit for the login. I can enter the `username` admin and the `password`foo, and the system will log me in.
Is my `security.yml`file wrong?

Comment: try add provider: in_memory to main firewall section.

Comment: @MertÖksüz same as before

Comment: try with this `pattern:   ^/admin` . under main section.

Comment: @MertÖksüz nothing

Comment: Why are you implementing login check? form_login takes care of that internally.  Make it go away and see what happens.  Also, it may be a copy/paste thing, but your form action makes no sense.

Comment: @Cerad Ok, I deleted the implementation of login check and set the check_path to login. I've changed the form action because if I write `<form action="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('login') ?>" method="post">` like in the example, I get the error: No route found for "POST /%3C"